# PHP code to open new resized window

Tags: php, javascript

I am not very well versed in PHP code, but I have an overall goal I hope someone can help me with. I have this code snippet from my site:

```
$show = false;
if($this->_general['post_ci_linkedin_show'])
{ 
    $url = urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID));
    $title = urlencode($post->post_title);
    $source = urlencode(get_bloginfo('url'));

    $surl = $this->_general['post_ci_linkedin_url'];
    $surl = str_replace('[%url]', $url, $surl);
    $surl = str_replace('[%title]', $title, $surl);                
    $surl = str_replace('[%source]', $source, $surl);

    $out .= '<a class="icon" href="'.$surl.'" rel="LinkedIn"><img class="unitPng" src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/img/icons/community/comm_LinkedIn.png" /></a>'; 
    $show = true;
}
```

Which produces:

```
src="http://www.websitename.com/subpage/mypage"
```

It produces other things obviously, like rel="blah" and such, but this is the part I want to tweak.

I want to change the PHP code snippet above so that the end result is:

```
href="javascript:void window.open('http://www.websitename.com/subpage/mypage','', 'height=700,width=500');"
```

I am just not sure of which parts of this code to change to get this result, I have tried just pasting it around the `.$surl.` but it gave me an error on my whole page.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but this is not WordPress specific. _and_ it is really bad for people with disabilities too.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you probably got an error was because your quotes were not escaped.

You have single quotes on the outside and double quotes on the inside. That's fine, but now you're trying to add more single quotes inside... those need to be escaped.

```
$out .= '<a class="icon" href="javascript:void window.open(\''.$surl.'\',\'\', \'height=700,width=500\');" rel="LinkedIn"><img class="unitPng" src="'.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/img/icons/community/comm_LinkedIn.png" /></a>';
```

Comment: Hi Sachleen, yes thank you that corrected the error issue! However, it still doesn't produce the function with the end result. Is there an alternate string I could use? PHP strings is definitely a weak area of mine and I appreciate your help so far.